# How do I divide certain cells in a dataframe by 1000

Tags: r, cell, divide

How would I divide certain cells in a column by `1000`?

I would like to create a function that divides values over `200` by `1000`

For example, in row 10 column 3 (weight), there is a value of `722.666667`.
[image: Excel Dataframe photo]

I used the function

```
Updins$weight <- as.numeric(Updins$weight)
Updins$body_length <- as.numeric(Updins$body_length)
Updins$tarsus_width <- as.numeric(Updins$tarsus_width)
```

for the desired columns so that they are numeric, and had previously used this function (below) with no success (I am a novice novice, so a lot of it I didn't understand!)

```
library(dplyr) 

test <- Updins %>%
   mutate(weight = ifelse(as.numeric(weight) > 199, 
                          as.character(as.numeric(weight)/1000), weight) 

head(test)
```

(Updins is the dataframe)

- which simply added 4 zeros to the vast majority of my `weight` values

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to make it work?

Comment: Why are you changing weight to a character after dividing it by 1000 ?

Comment: This was a suggestion from a colleague, would I need to change it to as.numeric(as.numeric(weight/1000)... ?

Comment: Can you load the file into R and share reproducible example using dput(dataframe)

Comment: You never need `as.numeric(as.numeric(.))`. As a matter of fact, in this case you don't even need `as.numeric(as.numeric(weight/1000))`, since `weight` is already numeric.

Comment: Please read the instructions on posting at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular provide reproducible input. No one wants to retype the data in images.

Comment: My apologies @G.Grothendieck, I am not yet used to the formatting when asking a question but will make the changes from here on out. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or the `tidyr` way

```
library(tidyverse)
updins <- updins %>% mutate(weight = ifelse(weight>200, weight/1000, weight))
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much! I didn't know tidyverse offered that capability

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I took just one column weight as a the sole column in the dataframe, see if it answeres your query and as Rui Barradas mentioned, you don't need as.numeric().

```
> df
# A tibble: 14 x 1
   weight
    <dbl>
 1 109.  
 2  79.4 
 3  23.6 
 4 118.  
 5  89.4 
 6 134.  
 7   4.92
 8 117.  
 9  64.6 
10 723.  
11 107.  
12  18.5 
13  12.0 
14  43.8 
> df$adjusted_weight <- ifelse(df$weight> 199, df$weight/1000, df$weight)
> df
# A tibble: 14 x 2
   weight adjusted_weight
    <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 109.           109.   
 2  79.4           79.4  
 3  23.6           23.6  
 4 118.           118.   
 5  89.4           89.4  
 6 134.           134.   
 7   4.92           4.92 
 8 117.           117.   
 9  64.6           64.6  
10 723.             0.723
11 107.           107.   
12  18.5           18.5  
13  12.0           12.0  
14  43.8           43.8  
>
```

Comment: It came up the console with the same values, I'm not too sure what the issue was, but thank you none the less!!

Answer (score 1):

An option in `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, adjusted_weight := weight][weight > 200, adjusted_weight := weight/1000]
```